# Matrices and basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can someone help me with the following exercise?

A basis is given by $(1,x+1,(x+1)^2)$. There is a unique linear trans-
formation T sending the basis $(1,x,x^2)$ to the basis $(1,x+1,(x+1)^2)$. Express the matrix of T relative to the basis $(1,x,x^2)$, and then also relative to the basis $(1,x+1,(x+1)^2)$. What is the relationship between these two matrices?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The columns of the matrix of $T$ relative to basis $B=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ are just the $T(e_1),\ T(e_2),\ T(e_3)$ (column-)vectors, *coordinated* in $B$.

For example, if $(e_1,e_2,e_3)=(1,x+1,(x+1)^2)$, then we have, by linearity of $T$,
$$T(e_2)=T(x+1)=T(x)+T(1)=x+1+1=x+2={\bf 1}\cdot (x+1)+{\bf 1}\cdot 1 \\
T(e_3)=T(x^2+2x+1)=(x+1)^2+2(x+1)+1$$
and you need the coordinates (=coefficients in the linear combination) w.r.t. this same $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ basis.

Comment: So for example, T(1,0,0)=(1,1,1) ?

Comment: I don't understand so much your hint

Comment: No. In your case first $e_1=1,\ e_2=x,\ e_3=x^2$. It is said that $T(1)=1,\ T(x)=x+1,\ T(x^2)=(x+1)^2={\bf 1}\cdot 1+{\bf 2}\cdot x+{\bf 1}\cdot x^2$, so the third column will be $\pmatrix{1\\2\\1}$.

Comment: So this is relative to the first basis (1,x,x^2) right ?

Comment: So the matrix that we obtain is of the form (c1,c2,c3) such that c1=(1,0,0), c2=(1,1,0) and c3= (1,2,1)

Comment: And relative to the basis (1,1+x,(1+x)^2) it's just $I_3$ right?

Comment: Can you just confirm my answer? But I still don't know what is the relationship between the two matrices.

Comment: What is the relationship between the two matrices

Comment: No, relative to the other basis, you have to find $T(1),\ T(x+1)$ and $T((x+1)^2)$, using the *linearity* of $T$. Then, you have to write these as linear combination with the *new basis* (and not the standard one). The relationship is: **inverses** I guess..

Comment: So the first matrix I mentioned (c1,c2,c3) is relative to (1,x,x^2) right ?

Comment: Yes. I got uncertain with my previous comment.. They are not inverses, sorry. (That's an answer for a similar question.) I update my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7561/discussion-between-user43758-and-berci)